# Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to string array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, string, json.net

I have a JSON Array like

```
model.Users =  ["Joe","Barny","Power","Tester"]
```

the model is `dynamic`

I want to convert `model.Users` to `string[] Users`

```
string[] Users = model.Users
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you attempted anything? What is the definition of model.Users because it seems like it is a string[] already. The "JSON.Array" you supplied doesn't look like JSON, it looks more like an array declaration.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

If `model.Users` is of type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray` try to call:

```
string[] Users = model.Users.ToObject<string[]>()
```

Answer (score -3):

```
string[] Users = new string[20];

int i = 0;

foreach ( string item in model.Users )
{
   Users[i] = item;
   i++;
}
```

Comment: if you are adding a new answer to a very old question which already has so many answers, try and add a sentence explaining why and how this is better or different.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27286720).